# Transparent Matching / Recommendation System

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, recommender-system, explainable-ai

I am thinking of a matching/recommendation algorithm which matches students to the right teachers for their individual problems.
The dataset would look like this:

Student

- Name
- Age
- Gender
- Weak Subjects
- Years of College...

Teachers

- Name
- Age
- Gender
- Specialzation
- Type (chilled or strict etc.)
- Learn methods
  etc.

Thus, both students and teachers have their own set of variables that might be relevant to the matching process. I have training data from past years where you can see what kind of students did best with what kind of teachers (Training set).

Based on this data, I would like to develop an algorithm which

**a) brings students to the best possible teacher (each teacher has unlimited capacity)**

**b) is *transparent* which variables have led to this decision.**

Especially point b) leads me to think that the first thoughts of classical Recommendation Systems or Siamese Neural Networks are not explainable enough.

Any ideas about algorithms or opinions about my previous thoughts that conventional recommendation systems are not quite suitable?

Comment: Do you want each teacher to supervise the same number of students, or the only critera is the individual match ? Also do you have a dataset with "matches" already verified, so you can learn to reproduce it ? If you don't, this means YOU have to specify what makes a good match for you : the problem might just be close to a clustering one, with the profiles of your professors as centroids.

Comment: @Adept #1 There is no maximum limit for teacher recommendations! The one and only criteria is to find good matching with good explainability why.
#2 We have a dataset with already certified matches. So there is some information about good matches included and we have training data for the algorithm.

Comment: The goal is to let the algorithm decide what makes a good match (based on the data from previous matches) and predict for the future with accuracy and explainability.

Comment: If you have enough already certified matches, you can make a supervised model with a "simple" algorithm (ex : Logistic Regression) with high explainability. You could make a model with rows for all possible matches, and train it labelling "1" for correct match you know. Then, for each student, you look for the best score through all rows.